# Remove a substring from a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, ecmascript-6

Having a function that has as arguments 2 parameters, first parameter is the string, the second one is the substring:

`function myFun(str, substr) {}`

I want to write a function that removes the content of the substring from the string. For example:

`str: My name is Chuck Norris`

`substr: is Chuck`

the returned value must be an array like this: `['My', 'name', 'Norris']`

I tried to do it like this:

```
function myFun(str, substr) {
    const result = str.replace(substr, '');
    const final = result.trim().split(' ');
    return final;
}
```

and I'm using it on hackerRank but some tests are failing.
Is it something wrong with it?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the Hackerrank problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second path for solution of this task:

You could set `.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ')`

[screenshot with result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMCn7.png)

```js
function myFun(str, substr) {
    const result = str.replace(substr, '').replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ');
    const final = result.trim().split(' ');
    return final;
}

let result = myFun('My name is Chuck Norris', 'is Chuck');

document.querySelector('#output').innerHTML = result

console.log(myFun('My name is Chuck Norris', 'is Chuck'))
```

```html
<div>Result:</div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You miss a filter

```js
const str = "My name is Chuck Norris"
const substr = "is Chuck"

function myFun(str, substr) {
  const result = str.replace(substr, '');
  const final = result.trim().split(' ').filter(a => a.trim() != "");
  return final;
}

console.log(myFun(str, substr))
```

Alternative

```js
const str = "My name is Chuck Norris"
const substr = "is Chuck"

function myFun(str, substr) {
  const re = new RegExp(`\\b${substr}\\b`)
  const result = str.replace(substr,"").replace(/\s+/g," ")
  const final = result.trim().split(' ');
  return final;
}

console.log(myFun(str, substr))
```

Comment: I tried with a longer example, with first string: "I am using hackerrank to improve programming" and the second string: "am hackerrank to improve". But it doesn't work for this one, it returns the original string as an array,  any idea why?

Comment: because there is no `using` in the second string